How to solve a elementary Wheatstone bridge with nodal analysis?
Coming here with a quick question about the following circuit. I believe it is a variation of a wheatstone bridge but as you can see, the power source is in line.
I am looking for the voltage at node V0. I already know it is 9.818V, I can solve this circuit easily by redrawing it and combining resistors, then working backwards. However, I am supposed to be able to solve it with Nodal Analysis, yet I cannot setup my equations correctly.
Frankly, even if I can solve it other ways, I am getting upset that I cannot figure out how to use Nodal Analysis on it lol. I've loved using NA up until this circuit.
Perhaps just a tip on how to deal with Nodal Analysis when a resistor is behind a power source? What's tricking me up is that I know the voltage at V1 is 12V, yet I know that 2k resistor behind the power source must affect something, but it is hard to see how it affects anything in the Analysis when the ground is at the other essential node.
Any tips would be appreciated!


The voltage at V1 is not 12 V. V1 - V2 = 12 V

ForeverDrivin - Hi, You changed the question significantly after receiving answers to the original version. That behaviour is not allowed here, since that change makes all the previous answers look wrong/incomplete, as they don't address the new parts you added to the question (this is sometimes called a "chameleon question"). After answers have been received then only clarifying a question is allowed, and even then, only if the change doesn't invalidate existing answers (your change does :( ). Therefore I reversed (rolled-back) your changes to the question (and related comments).

SamGibson - While I certainly appreciate you deleting everything I wrote (and my comments) instead of just amending it to the original post, I understand the issue. I re-edited it while leaving the entirety of the original post. I'll be mindful of that rule in the future!

@ForeverDrivin - Don't be sarcastic. All site members are required to comply with the Code of Conduct. That is your one warning. || Your previous parts were not deleted - they remain in the version history. A rollback is standard procedure here, whether you like that or not. As you're new here, instead of attacking me for helping educate you to the site rules (as this is not a forum and changes to the question should not invalidate existing answers or make them look incomplete), please ask if you don't understand something. TY

SamGibson I do apologize if that came across more insulting than joking! Light hearted sense of humor over here. As I stated I will be mindful of that rule going forward!

@ForeverDrivin - As I tried to explain before, it is too late to change the question, in this case by adding new questions, after answers were given to the original question. That is "forum-type" behaviour and is not allowed here. Again, I have reverted the edit and removed the related comments. (You can read more about "chameleon questions" by searching on [meta.se].)

(continued) If, as it seems, you have a follow-on question to this one, then please ask it as a new question. It should be self-contained (so it should not require people to read this one) but it should include a link back here for those who do want to. You can add a single comment to any relevant answers here, linking to the new question and inviting (not demanding) them to help with the new question, if they want to. || Please do not alter this question again. TY

@SamGibson - Ah, I see. I understand now, I just did not interpret adding to the post as significantly "altering" it, I left the original post in tact for the previously mentioned reason of not wanting to invalidate people's answers. I will make a new question of it then. Funny enough I did not originally make a new question because most forums have rules against crowding sections/tags with super similar posts, so you're definitely right on "forum behavior" being prohibited! Lol. It is good to know I need to re-post it every time! I'll try to avoid editing in general

The node at V1 is the only interesting one. The nodes at V0 and V2 are trivial. The node at ground has the same currents as V1, but from a different perspective.


Hey Mattman, thank you for the reply. I quickly worked this equation out and it implies that the voltage at V1 is 72? Did I somehow mix this up?

@ForeverDrivin - Yes, V1 = 72 V. V0 = 48 V. V2 = 60 V.

How are we generating more voltage than the power supply is putting out?

@ForeverDrivin - Mistake, I will fix it.

@ForeverDrivin - Fixed, double checked with simulator this time.

Perfect. Those numbers are what my sim says too. That also answers my question perfectly! I was not sure if it was correct to say that I1 = (12-V1)/2k, since the resistor is not specifically between the source and the node. It seems that as long as the resistor(s) and source are on the same wire, we can apply nodal voltage regardless of order, if that sounds correct? Thanks!

I made the circuit analysis based on the network topology and the creation of the tableau with which I determine voltages at the nodes and branches as well as the relative currents. Note that the resulting currents are all negative, that is, they have opposite directions to those of the Digraph:


It is premature and probably incorrect to say \$V_1=12V\$.
\$V_1\$ is at one end of a voltage source whose potential difference is 12V. \$V_2\$ is at the other end of that same source, so all you can say is that:
$$ V_1-V_2 = 12V $$
That's a statement about the difference between potentials \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$, and doesn't imply any absolute potential at all.
The 2kΩ resistor at the source's negative end also has a potential difference across it, which may or may not be zero. Because you don't yet know that potential difference, you may not assume that \$V_2=0V\$, and you cannot claim that \$V_1 = +12V\$.
I repeat:
$$ V_1 - V_2 = 12V $$
$$ V_1 = V_2 + 12V $$
Your statement \$V_1=12V\$ could only be true if \$V_2=0V\$, and that's almost certainly not the case.

You can forget about ground for the moment. KVL doesn't care about absolute potentials, it cares only about potential differences, such as \$V_1-V_0\$ in your circuit. Therefore, just redraw it in a friendlier form, and do what you would usually do. Label all the currents, and the potential differences, paying attention to voltage polarity and current direction, so that they conform with passive sign convention:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I've also changed the node names, because digits would be confusing. Your node V0 corresponds to my node B.
Start with KCL:
$$ I_1 - I_2 - I_3 = 0 $$
Then KVL. First loop ACDA:
$$ - V_3 - V_4 + V_1 = 0 $$
Loop ABCA:
$$ -V_2 - V_5 + V_3 = 0 $$
Lastly Ohm's law:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_2 &= I_2R_2 \\
V_3 &= I_3R_3\\
V_4 &= I_1R_4 \\
V_5 &= I_2R_5 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
That's seven independent equations in seven unknowns, \$I_1\$, \$I_2\$, \$I_3\$, \$V_2\$, \$V_3\$, \$V_4\$ and \$V_5\$. You should be able to find a single solution for all of them.
Once you know the potential difference \$V_5\$, then finding the absolute potential \$V_B\$ is simply another application of KVL:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_B &= V_C + V_5 \\ \\
&= 0V + V_5 \\ \\
&= V_5 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Obviously you don't need to redraw the schematic, you could have arrived at the same solution using existing node names, and you would usually combine Ohm's law and KVL into a single step. I think maybe you just got hung up on the idea that "ground" is somehow changing things. It isn't.

Hey Simon, thank you for the reply! I can, and have already, worked it out this way. My main question is why Nodal Analysis tricks me up. Using the two essential nodes in the circuit, how would I write the equation main equation? I should only need one with NA. Assuming Va as an active essential node and Vc as ground, it seems like the equation is I1=I2+I3. I know I2 = Va-0/6k (combined resistors) and I3=Va-0/4k. But what of I1? I cannot figure out how to set that one up properly to get the 6.54volts that should be across both the 4k resistor and the two series resistors.

@ForeverDrivin How is $I_1 = I_2 + I_3$ different from $I_1-I_2-I_3=0$?

@ForeverDrivin Be careful with your parentheses: $I_2=(V_A-0)/6k=V_A/6k$.

@ForeverDrivin I suggest you update your question with your own working, because it's not clear at all where you are tripping up.

Its not that our KCL applications are any different, what Im having issues with is doing Node Voltage Method specifically. I can work out the problem in the way you described but when you use Node Voltage Method, you should only need (n-1) number of equations for (n) essential nodes. That means I should be able to analyze the general voltages of this circuit with only one equation, or so I thought. That is my confusion, however I am going to try Mattman's response later today

@SimonFitch - Hi, Thanks as always for your help here. FYI it is too late for the OP to change the question, after answers have been given to the original one. I have explained that in comments under the question. Moving the goalposts (aka "chameleon questions") are not uncommon with new OPs who use forum-like behaviour on SE. However we can't have questions extended after genuine answers to the original question were given. Otherwise those all look incomplete as they can't include answers to the new parts of the question. There is no expectations for answer-writers to chase a moving question.

When you have a voltage source, as you do, then just introduce a current:

eqv0 = Eq( v0/2e3 + v0/4e3, v1/2e3 )           # KCL/nodal for V0
eqv1 = Eq( v1/2e3 + v1/4e3, v0/2e3 + Ix )      # KCL/nodal for V1
eqv2 = Eq( v2/2e3 + Ix, 0 )                    # KCL/nodal for V2
eqkvl = Eq( v1, v2 + 12 )                      # KVL for (V1 - V2)
solve( [ eqv0, eqv1, eqv2, eqkvl ], [ v0, v1, v2, Ix ] )
{v0: 4.36363636363636,
 v1: 6.54545454545455,
 v2: -5.45454545454545,
 Ix: 0.00272727272727273}

I've no idea where you got your figure of 9.818. But Mattman944 has it right.
Added

9.818 is what my sim software says V0 is, I dont know how the 9.818 number comes up either, however it agrees that the voltage across both
the 4k resistor and the two series is 6.54V. Mattman's original answer
gave 72 volts, that's why I was skeptical lol. I will try out his
updated response later today.

You aren't using the sim software correctly or else it has a bug/failure to perform.
See the following:


9.818 is what my sim software says V0 is, I dont know how the 9.818 number comes up either, however it agrees that the voltage across both the 4k resistor and the two series is 6.54V. Mattman's original answer gave 72 volts, that's why I was skeptical lol. I will try out his updated response later today.

@ForeverDrivin I've addressed your work in an addition to my answer. Do note that a proper simulation confirms the results I achieved using theory and math.

I will double check in PSpice as well, however I got the 9.818 value from the falstad.com/circuit applet. It's good to know that this applet may fail occasionally!

Learn about forming a supernode between \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$  which combines nodes 1 and 2 and \$V_1\$ - \$V_2\$  =12 Since the GND is not at node 2, a supernode is necessary.
With KVL and nodal analysis,
$$V_1 - V_2  =12 \tag1 $$
$$ \frac{V_o - V_1}{2k} + \frac{V_0}{4k} = 0 \tag 2 $$
At the supernode 1-2,
$$ \frac{V_1 - V_0}{2K} + \frac{V_1}{4k} + \frac{V_2}{2k}= 0 \tag 3 $$
Solve for \$V_0\$ , \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ with Kramer's rule.

The author appears to specifically request a nodal analysis approach. To the degree possible.

Thanks Amit, I will look into super nodes!

if you like an answer use upvote or select best answer.
